# SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE and SO_REUSEADDR confusion

Tags: sockets, network-programming, winsock, winsock2

(Running on VS2017, Win7 x64)

I am confused about the point of `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`.  And yes, I've read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I'm obviously not getting it.

I have the following simple code in two separate processes.  As expected, because I enable `SO_REUSEADDR` on both sockets, the second process's bind succeeds.  **If I don't enable this on any one of these sockets, the second bind will not succeed**.

```
#define PORT 5150
SOCKET sockListen;
if ((sockListen = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("WSASocket() failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

int optval = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockListen, SOL_SOCKET, `SO_REUSEADDR`, (char*)&optval, sizeof(optval)) == -1)
    return -1;

SOCKADDR_IN InternetAddr;
InternetAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
InternetAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.15.20.97");
InternetAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (::bind(sockListen, (PSOCKADDR)&InternetAddr, sizeof(InternetAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("bind() failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
```

So doesn't having to enable `SO_REUSEADDR` for both sockets make `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` unnecessary - if I don't want anyone to foricibly bind to my port, I just don't enable `SO_REUSEADDR` in that process?

The only difference I can see is that if I enable `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` in the first process, then attempt a bind in the second process, that second bind will fail with

a) `WSAEADDRINUSE` if I **don't** enable `SO_REUSEADDR` in that second process

b) `WSAEACCES` if I **do** enable `SO_REUSEADDR` in that second process

So I tried enabling both `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` and `SO_REUSEADDR` in the first process but found that whichever one I attempted second failed with `WSAEINVAL`.

Note also that I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/2369597) past question but what that says isn't what I'm seeing: it states

> A socket with SO_REUSEADDR can always bind to exactly the same source
>   address and port as an already bound socket, even if the other socket
>   did not have this option set when it was bound

Now if that were the case then I can definitely see the need for `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but I cannot see it; can someone clarify please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs, SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE became available on Windows NT4 SP4; before that there was **only** SO_REUSEADDR. So both being present has (also) historical reasons.

I think of SO_REUSEADDR as the *intention* to share an address (which is only really useful for UDP multicast. For unicast or TCP it really doesn´t do much since the bahaviour is non-deterministic for both sockets).

SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE is a *security measure* to avoid my (server) application´s traffic being hijacked / rendered useless by a later binding to the same IP/port.

As I see it, you *need* SO_REUSEADDR for UDP multicats, and you *need* SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE as a security measure for server applications.

Comment: Thanks.  But I still don't see the point of `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`; if I don't set `SO_REUSEADDR` in my server, no malicious app can possibly hijack my traffic (as I've shown above) even if it itself sets `SO_REUSEADDR`.  Therefore I don't need `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`?  What is `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` giving me that I don't get by not setting `SO_REUSEADDR`?

Comment: Operationally you´re right, but as the docs mention, "exclusive" was introduced later, and on top they made changes to increase security. So you get a mix of historical stuff (not to speak of differences to UNIX/Linux sockets). Also, I find using "exclusive" explicitly increases code readability...

Comment: Why introduce `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` if simply not setting `SO_REUSEADDR` in the server prevents a malicious client from binding to the same port? The only thing I can think of is that in earlier versions, not setting `SO_REUSEADDR` did *not* prevent a malicious client - hence the introduction of `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` to address that-and in more recent versions, the behaviour of `SO_REUSEADDR` has changed so that not setting it in a server prevents a malicious client binding,thus rendering `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` not necessary.But this isn't documented anywhere that I can find,what do you think?

Comment: That is mentioned in the second table of the MSDN (XP and earlier): if the first bind is done without any option ("default"), then the second (with SO_REUSEADDR) would have succeeded.

Comment: Excellent.  I didn't spot that the second table applies to XP and earlier (hence I'm not going to see that behaviour on my Win7 box) and the third table applies to Server 2003 and beyond.  Thanks!